# Files in red in project navigator after importing pod file

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

I imported a pod file (https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka) and I have files in my project navigator that are either in red and other with question marks.

Can anyone tell me if it's a problem and if so, how to solve it?[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A file in red means it doesn't currently exist or Xcode is unable to find it. In your screenshot the framework and application don't exist because you haven't built them yet. You can make the red go away by building the framework and application.

The question marks next to the folders and files means they are not part of your version control repository. Control-click on a file and choose Source Control > Add to add the file to the repository.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but should every file be added to my repository?

Comment: Add the files whose changes you want to track. I have not used CocoaPods so I cannot tell you what related files should be added. Do a search on this site for **Xcode gitignore** to learn about what files you should not add.